# jQuery remove div which added with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

[image: This is capture]

I add some div with jQuery, Every div have a cancel button for remove the div.
But div remove button not working.
Here is my div remove code

```
$('.canceltag').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
```

And here is my full jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var BaseURL   = $(".BaseURL").val();
    var fPeople = $('.fPeople').val();
    $('.fPeople').typeahead({
        ajax: {
            url: ""+ BaseURL +"json/tag",
            method: 'post',
            triggerLength: 1
        },
        onSelect: (function(item){
            var aprid = item.value;
            var aprname = item.text;
            var nappr   = " <i class='tagcover'>"+ aprname +" <b class='cursor_pointer text-danger canceltag'>X</b><input type='hidden' name='tag[]' value='"+ aprid +"'></i>";
            $(".selectedname").append(nappr);

            $('.fPeople').val('');
        })
    });

    $('.canceltag').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation to attach event to dynamically created element appended to `document`

```
// attach event to `.canceltag` parent element
$(".selectedname").on("click", ".canceltag", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: or $(".selectedname").delegate("click", ".canceltag", function() { ... });

Comment: Thanks for your valuable info